# How to Remotely Block and Unblock any application on Windows

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am creating a program using Java Sockets in which I capture the client desktop and send messaging to client. Its working properly but now I want to block Client applications like Notepad, MS-Word, etc.

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: You can use JNA and call User32's [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`FindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx) function to check on selected applications and [kill their process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686722(v=vs.85).aspx) after checking [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to do using pure java API.
I do not know what do you mean when you say "block". The easiest way is to check from time to time running processes and kill one named "notepad" by executing `taskkill` from java.

If you wish to achieve effect of inactivity of application, i.e. user sees the notepad but cannot type you can do the following.

You have to check which application is on front. There is no clean pure java solution for this but you can probably write VBScript or JScript that does this task and run it from java. Once you detected that notepad is on top create transparent window (or even probably half-transparent window) that occupies full screen. Bring it on top. User will not be able to type into notepad because your window is on top but will see it.

Here is reference how to create transparent windows: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for reply AlexR. Block means when Client wants to open Notepad is does not open. or other words we can say that we are block execution of application in windows. can its possible ?

Comment: Thanks AlexR ... i am got solution using taskkill.